# How can I set the value of an input text field in Bokeh from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, textfield, bokeh

I have created a simple input object like this:

```python
self.dummy_text = TextInput()
self.dummy_text.css_classes = ['dummy_text']
```

And I want to recover the value of this field with another control. For example this button:

```python
self.dummy_button = Button(label="Foo", button_type="success")
self.dummy_button.css_classes = ['dummy_button']
```

If I change the value of the input text field by hand, the button get the input text value well. But if I modify the value by JavaScript (jQuery) like this the value is not received at all:

```javascript
$("#bokeh_iframe").contents().find(".dummy_text input").val('text value')
```

I have opened bokeh in the iframe with id `bokeh_iframe`. I  need to use `find` because with a direct selector is not working. Finally I invoke the button click method like this:

```javascript
$("#bokeh_iframe").contents().find(".dummy_button button").get(0).click();
```

The button method looks like this:

```python
def dummy_button(self):
    dummy_text_value = self.dummy_text.value
```

What is happening? Do I need to tell to bokeh to synchronize the data in some other way? Do I have to find another way to fill the field by JavaScript?

Note: I need to do this workaround to run some actions in the bokeh server from an external application (Electron, that is built with Node)

Note2: Another element: `prevObject: jQuery.fn.init(1)` appears with the input and button objects, could be that the problem? That's why I need to use `get(0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the BokehJS machinery to auto-magically detect and synchronize changes to model properties (such as the input widget value), you normally have to set the `.value` property *on the BokehJS model object*, not by changing the HTML attribute directly.

However, Bokeh has never really had in mind the use-case of manipulating Bokeh models from "external" JavaScript, so it is definitely not optimized to make that easy or simple. When Bokeh renders documents in a page, it leaves an index of top-level views in a `window.Bokeh.index` object. So one definitely workable approach is to root through that index tree to find the Bokeh model for the input widget you care about, and then update the `.value` field on it.

However, it *may work* in this particular case to set the value on the HTML element, and also explicitly trigger the `change` event:

```
$("#bokeh_iframe").contents().find(".dummy_text input")
    .val('text value')
    .trigger('change');
```

That would certainly easier, but is untested (I don't have the bandwidth to try and construct and test a full example, regrettably.)

---

Alternatively there is some way to re-express your intent using a `CustomJS` callback, that will be preferable, since Bokeh models can be made easily available to `CustomJS` JavaScript code via the `args` property.

Comment: I appreciate all your help. Do you mean to use the args attribute like this? `CustomJS(args=dict(source=source), code=""" [...] """)`. This way I would send the argument from Python to JavsScript. Actually I am intening to do the opposite, to send a parameter from JavaScript (from the external application, not from the CustomJS code) to a python method. That's why I am filling the dummy text field with this parameter. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I tested the `trigger('change')` solution but it does not work :(

Comment: I have also tried the `window.document.Bokeh.index` solution and it works. So the solution would be this one: `var models = window.Bokeh.index[Object.keys(window.Bokeh.index)[0]].model.document._all_models; var input_dummy_text = models[dummy_text_id]; input_dummy_text.value = 'new value'`

Comment: I accepted your answer as correct, anyway you are free to update it

Comment: I was doing something similar today and discovered that .trigger('change') doesn't trigger the change event on bokeh's input widget, but directly dispatching an event does. `inputelement.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'))`